# How to set combo.SelectedItem.Index = 0; code behind in ext.net 2.5 version?

Tags: combobox, ext.net, selectedindex

I have upgrated project from ext.net 1.0 to 2.5, new feature combo selectindex at .aspx we have property in ext.net 2.5 like

```
 <ext:ComboBox runat="server">
      <SelectedItems> 
        <ext:ListItem Index="0" />
        </SelectedItems>   
    </ext:ComboBox>
```

to set index but the requirement is something like I have to set the combo index at code behind , below code is working fine with 1.0

```
ComboBox .SelectedItem.Index = 0;
```

but its not working in 2.5 .Please suggest!
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me when I was adding elements by their values:

```
ComboBox.SelectedItems.Add(new Ext.Net.ListItem { Value = selectedItemValue});
```

So, you could simply adapt it to your needs if you like:

```
ComboBox.SelectedItems.Add(new Ext.Net.ListItem { Index = 0 });
```